SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position
Возникло исключение:
  File "C:\Users\zanae\geme\game.py", line 4, in <module>
    from anggrnpslogics import anggrnps
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 5-6: malformed \N character escape (anggrnpslogics.py, line 4)

main.py
import pygame
import sys
from playerlogics import Player
from Anggrnpslogics import Anggrnps #проблемная строка

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
#размер экрана
lengthx = 1600
widthy = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((lengthx, widthy))
#название
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
#проверка работы fps
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 8

local = pygame.image.load('imege\local.png')
px = 600
py = 400
pspeed = 4
rightborder = lengthx - 50
leftborder = 50
downborder = widthy - 50
upborder = 50
border = [
    rightborder,
    leftborder,
    downborder,
    upborder
]
npsspeed = 1





#основной цикл
running = True
while running:
    #цвет экрана
    screen.blit(local, (0, 0)) 
    pygame.display.flip()

    #логика player
    pm = Player
    Player.movement(pm, px, py, lengthx, widthy, pspeed, border, screen)
    px = Player.x
    py = Player.y
    #логика 1 anggr nps
    anps = Anggrnps
    Anggrnps.movement(anps, px, py, npsspeed, border, screen)
    


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                screen.blit(settings, (270, 480))

Anggrnpslogics
    import pygame
import random
class Anggrnps ():
    demondown = pygame.image.load('imege\NPS_Animation\Npsdbd.png')
    anim = 0
    direc = 0
    randomdirec = random.randint(0, 8)
    randomspeed = random.choice([0, 4])
    randomlen = random.randint(0, 5)
    direc = 0
    i = 0
    npsx = 1200
    npsy = 400

    def movement(self, px, py, speed, border, screen):
        run = 1
        zoneanggr = 50
        #D
        if  self.npsx < border[0]:
            direc = 'reght'
            if px - zoneanggr < self.npsx:
                self.npsx += speed * run
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
            elif self.randomdirec == 0:
                if self.randomlen == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    for self.i in range (self.randomlen):
                        self.npsx += self.randomspeed
                        screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
                self.i = 0
        #A
        elif  self.npsx > border[1]:
            direc = 'left'
            if px + zoneanggr > self.npsy:
                self.npsx -= speed * run
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
            elif self.randomdirec == 1:
                for self.i in range (self.randomlen):
                    self.npsy += self.randomspeed
                    screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
                self.i = 0
        #S
        elif  self.npsy < border[2]:
            direc = 'down'
            if py - zoneanggr > self.npsy:
                self.npsy += speed * run
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
            elif self.randomdirec == 2:
                for self.i in range (self.randomlen):
                    self.npsy += self.randomspeed
                    screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
                self.i = 0
        #W
        elif  self.npsy > border[3]:
            direc = 'up'
            if py - zoneanggr > self.npsy:
                self.npsy -= speed * run
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
            elif self.randomdirec == 3:
                for self.i in range (self.randomlen):
                    self.npsy -= self.randomspeed
                    screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
                self.i = 0
        #DW
        elif  self.npsx > border[0] and self.npsy > border[3]:
            direc = 'right'
            if py - zoneanggr > self.npsy and px - zoneanggr < self.npsx:
                self.npsy -= speed * run
                self.npsy += speed * run
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
            elif self.randomdirec == 4:
                for self.i in range (self.randomlen):
                    self.npsy -= self.randomspeed
                    self.npsx += self.randomspeed
                    screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
                self.i = 0
        #WA 
        elif  self.npsx > border[1] and self.npsy > border[3]:
            direc = 'left'
            if py - zoneanggr > self.npsy:
                self.npsx -= speed * run
                self.npsy -= speed * run
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
            elif self.randomdirec == 5:
                for self.i in range (self.randomlen):
                    self.npsy -= self.randomspeed
                    self.npsx -= self.randomspeed
                    screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
                self.i = 0
        #AS  
        elif  self.npsx > border[1] and self.npsy < border[2]:
            direc = 'left'
            if px + zoneanggr > self.npsy and py + zoneanggr < self.npsy:
                self.npsx -= speed * run
                self.npsy += speed * run
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
            elif self.randomdirec == 6:
                for self.i in range (self.randomlen):
                    self.npsy += self.randomspeed
                    self.npsy += self.randomspeed
                    screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
                self.i = 0
        #SD  
        elif  self.npsx < border[0] and self.npsy < border[2]:
            direc = 'right'
            if px - zoneanggr < self.npsx and py - zoneanggr > self.npsy:
                self.npsx += speed * run
                self.npsy += speed * run
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
            elif self.randomdirec == 7:
                for self.i in range (self.randomlen):
                    self.npsx += self.randomspeed
                    self.npsy += self.randomspeed
                    screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))
                self.i = 0
        else:
            if self.anim == False:
                pass
            else:
                screen.blit(self.demondown, (self.npsx, self.npsy))


Дело в том, что символы \<буква> Python распознаёт как специальный символ. Что бы сказать ему, что это просто символы, нужно поставить перед строкой букву r:
demondown = pygame.image.load(r'imege\NPS_Animation\Npsdbd.png')
#                             ^

